# Get field description from a query in vba

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I'm developing a function to get the data from a query. I want to have both the field name (same from DB) and the field description before my data. I found how to get the field name but I did not find a way to get the description, can someone help me?

This is my current code to get the field name (and how I tried to get the description is commented):

```
'-Get the table's data
Set rs = con.Execute("SELECT * FROM " & Sh.name)

'-Set the name of the fields
Dim TheCells As range
Set TheCells = Sh.range("A2")
For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    TheCells.Offset(0, i).Value = rs.Fields(i).name
    'TheCells.Offset(1, i).Value = rs.Fields(i).Properties("Description").Value
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ADOX to get properties of columns.

```
Sub GetFieldDesc()

    Dim axCat As ADOX.Catalog
    Dim axTbl As ADOX.Table
    Dim adCon As ADODB.Connection
    Dim axProp As ADOX.Property

    'Create an ado connection
    Set adCon = New ADODB.Connection
    adCon.Open sCON

    'Point the adox catalog to that connection
    Set axCat = New ADOX.Catalog
    Set axCat.ActiveConnection = adCon

    'Pick your table
    Set axTbl = axCat.Tables("tblCurrentPriceDate")

    Debug.Print axTbl.Columns(0).Properties("Description").Value

End Sub
```

Set a reference to `ActiveX Data Objects` and to `ADO Ext. x.x for DLL and Security`

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any way to get the description from the recordset. What I found is a way to get the description from the properties in the database - basically running another query to get the description.
How to write the query:

[SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161505/use-a-query-to-access-column-description-in-sql)

[IBM](http://www.itjungle.com/fhg/fhg051111-story01.html)