# How to see content/description of a function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to see content/description of a function in SQL Server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15162504/9753352

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/  Don't post and then answer your own question when the answer you provide is an exact dupe of an existing SO post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sp_helptext N'objectName'
```

objectName can be a stored procedure or a function name

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`sp_helptext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/view-the-definition-of-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017) like

```
sp_helptext procedure_name
```

Answer (score 0):

below is an example you can follow this

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
    GO  
    -- Get the function name, definition, and relevant properties  
    SELECT sm.object_id,   
       OBJECT_NAME(sm.object_id) AS object_name,   
       o.type,   
       o.type_desc,   
       sm.definition,  
       sm.uses_ansi_nulls,  
       sm.uses_quoted_identifier,  
       sm.is_schema_bound,  
       sm.execute_as_principal_id  
    -- using the two system tables sys.sql_modules and sys.objects  
    FROM sys.sql_modules AS sm  
    JOIN sys.objects AS o ON sm.object_id = o.object_id  
    -- from the function 'dbo.ufnGetProductDealerPrice'  
    WHERE sm.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.ufnGetProductDealerPrice')  
    ORDER BY o.type;  
    GO
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/view-user-defined-functions?view=sql-server-2017